Time Series Forecasting by Country
I want to do a time series forecasting on multiple columns by country. The data set is as followed (putting in random numbers for the example)
     Year - Population M&F - Population M - Population F 
Albania  1950 -  23541         -  74588       - 55874
Albania  1951 -  59856         -  8598        - 25782
.
.
.

We have all countries from EU and every time from 1950 to 2023. How can I make a time series forecasting and predict the numbers till +-2100 but per country so I do not have to do this for every country separate but in bulk?
I was thinking to use this resource https://www.kaggle.com/code/prashant111/complete-guide-on-time-series-analysis-in-python for the time series analysis, only how to do it per country.
I believe Time Series Forecasting will be the best way to predict the future population. If you have more tips & tricks, please share with me.
https://www.kaggle.com/code/prashant111/complete-guide-on-time-series-analysis-in-python
This coding in the file is with a very simple two columns done, I know I need to further adapt the code but I was thinking of 'groupby' only again as I am new to it, I don't now how/if it would work.

Please edit your question to (1) clarify which numbers you are trying to forecast, I assume population but this is unclear.  (2) Show your attempted solution, and include an example of the expected output given your sample input.  (3) DO NOT post images of code,data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.  Images can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Also, refrain from posting links to problem definitions and/or explanations Instead, incorporate the explanation into your question directly.

Thanks for your feedback! I am new to it all so still figuring it out. I'll pay attention to your points next time I post a question. For now I have found an answer :
for country in countries:
country_data = df[df['Country'] == country]
